# Combining cleveref, subcaption, and subtable word prefix

Tags: subcaption, cleveref

I would like to use `subcaption` package to call subtables "panels". The subtables for Table 1 would be "Panel A" and Panel B". I can do this fine, but when I use `\cref{tab:01a}` for Table 1 Panel A I get something like "table 1Panel A". I would like to get back the space between "table 1" and "Panel A". It would also be great to make "Panel" case sensitive, but that is less important -- I can just make everything title case.

```
\documentclass{article} 

% tables and captions
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% fix table captions
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Panel \Alph{subtable}}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon, belowskip=12pt}

\usepackage{cleveref}   

\begin{document}

I want to refer to \cref{tab:01}, \cref{tab:01a}, and \cref{tab:01b}.

\begin{table}
    \caption{Outer.}
    \label{tab:01}

    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \caption{Inner a.}
        \label{tab:01a}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            1 \\
            \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \caption{Inner b.}
        \label{tab:01b}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            2 \\
            \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This gives "table 1" and "Panel A" without spaces.

[image]

Comment: You could change `\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Panel \Alph{subtable}}` to `\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{ Panel \Alph{subtable}}`. (Note the extra space before "Panel".)

Comment: @Mico - thanks. Can this fail me in subtable captions? Or is it really that easy?!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can this fail me in subtable captions?"

Comment: @Mico - I am not sure, either? :) I am still a little confused about when I need `~` to get spaces and avoid run-ons.

Comment: @Mico - But your solution works! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

% tables and captions
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% fix table captions
\renewcommand\subtablename{Panel}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\Alph{subtable}}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon, belowskip=12pt}

\usepackage{cleveref}
  \crefname{subtable}{panel}{panels}%
  \Crefname{subtable}{Panel}{Panels}%

\begin{document}

I want to refer to \cref{tab:01}, \cref{tab:01a}, and \cref{tab:01b}.

\begin{table}
    \caption{Outer.}
    \label{tab:01}

    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \caption{Inner a.}
        \label{tab:01a}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            1 \\
            \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \caption{Inner b.}
        \label{tab:01b}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            2 \\
            \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for having the courage to propose a solution that differs considerably from what the OP said he wants. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could change

```
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Panel \Alph{subtable}}
```

to

```
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{ Panel \Alph{subtable}}
```

Note the extra space before "Panel".